# NS_ERROR_FAILURE with soundcloud api

Tags: javascript, api, http, soundcloud

I've worked on this website: http://umpire.mxcmaxime.net/ a while ago but recently I had a correction to do and I saw that the soundcloud player is not working with firefox anymore and I get a NS_ERROR_FAILURE error in the console.

The player works fine on chrome and I searched a solution without success so I'm asking from the stackoverflow community to get some help.

Thank you, Maxime